# How to parse complex type web service xml response along with datatype in android

Tags: java, android, webservice-client

My web service is basically `WCF`. I am using ksoap2 and it is working fine but I need a solution which provide functionality like `wsimport`.

my soap response in looks like

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >

    <s:Body
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

        <UserLoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" >

            <UserLoginResult>

                <DocumentElement xmlns="" >

                    <xs:schema
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
                        id="DocumentElement" >

                        <xs:element
                            name="DocumentElement"
                            msdata:IsDataSet="true"
                            msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" >

                            <xs:complexType>

                                <xs:choice
                                    maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                    minOccurs="0" >

                                    <xs:element name="Table" >

                                        <xs:complexType>

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="UserID"
                                                type="xs:int" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="UserName"
                                                type="xs:string" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="LevelID"
                                                type="xs:int" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="LevelName"
                                                type="xs:string" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="RoleID"
                                                type="xs:int" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="RoleName"
                                                type="xs:string" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="ServiceProviderID"
                                                type="xs:int" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="ServiceProvider"
                                                type="xs:string" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="ClientID"
                                                type="xs:int" />

                                            <xs:attribute
                                                name="ClientName"
                                                type="xs:string" />
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:choice>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:schema>

                    <Table
                        ClientID="0"
                        ClientName=""
                        LevelID="1"
                        LevelName="IT Team"
                        RoleID="1"
                        RoleName="IT Admin"
                        ServiceProvider=""
                        ServiceProviderID="0"
                        UserID="1"
                        UserName="Admin" />
                </DocumentElement>
            </UserLoginResult>
        </UserLoginResponse>
    </s:Body>

</s:Envelope>
```

I have already tried wsdl2code to generate proxy class for my `WCF`but It generates only requests and not responses. Is there any other tool for `WCF` in android? .NET users easily parsing the above xml as dataset to datatable. can I use similar functionality in android?

Please lead me to get a flexible solution.

Comment: http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html. check this

Comment: my web service contains 160 methods ... it is very painful to write those classes